# Summing up values from one column based on values in other column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe something like below,

```
Timestamp                     count
20180702-06:26:20             50
20180702-06:27:11             10
20180702-07:05:10             20
20180702-07:10:10             30
20180702-08:27:11             40
```

I want output something like below,

```
Timestamp                  Sum_of_count
20180702-06                   60
20180702-07                   50
20180702-08                   40
```

Basically, I need to find sum of count for every hour.
Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need separate value some way - one is [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and seelct first lists by `str[0]` and then aggregate `sum`:

```
s = df['Timestamp'].str.split(':', n=1).str[0]
df1 = df['count'].groupby(s).sum().reset_index(name='Sum_of_count')
```

Or convert values to `datetimes` by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and get values by [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S')

s = df['Timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H')
```

---

```
df1 = df['count'].groupby(s).sum().reset_index(name='Sum_of_count')
print (df1)
     Timestamp  Sum_of_count
0  20180702-06            60
1  20180702-07            50
2  20180702-08            40
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
In [252]: df.groupby(df.Timestamp.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H'))['count'].sum()
Out[252]:
Timestamp
2018-07-02-06    60
2018-07-02-07    50
2018-07-02-08    40
Name: count, dtype: int64

In [254]: (df.groupby(df.Timestamp.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H'))['count'].sum()
             .reset_index(name='Sum_of_count'))
Out[254]:
       Timestamp  Sum_of_count
0  2018-07-02-06            60
1  2018-07-02-07            50
2  2018-07-02-08            40
```